# I18N Not Working in Aurelia - LNG option required

Tags: aurelia, i18next

For some reason Aurelia requires lng as an option when configuring i18N but the tradition I18N options do not.  The problem is, when I try to configure it the use language detection, the lng option is overriding the detected language.  How can you use language detection?

```
plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-i18n'), 
      (instance) => {
                     let aliases = ['t', 'i18n'];
                     TCustomAttribute.configureAliases(aliases);

                     instance.i18next
                             .use(LngDetector)
                             .use(XHR);

                     return instance.setup({
                                            lng:'en',
                                            attributes: aliases,
                                            backend: {
                                               loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
                                            },
                                            detection : {
                                               order: ['querystring', 'navigator', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'htmlTag'],
                                            },
                                            debug: false,
                                            fallbackLng: 'en'
                                           });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with one of the more recent versions of the plugin